# Changing the date format of auth.log

Tags: logs, date, rsyslog

I was looking to change the date format in which `auth.log` logs information. I could not find a way to do it. Is there a method to do this? My system uses rsyslog.

Comment: AFAIK, `auth.log` is written by syslog, so that this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402162/changing-date-format-in-syslog

Comment: I am working on an Ubuntu box. The solution presented there does not seem to work. I updated the rsyslog.conf instead there.

Comment: Do you want to change the date format only in that file, or in all log files?

Comment: I would like to change the date format of auth.log. However, I do not really care much about the date format of other log files as well.

Comment: This answer seems to be helpful for your task: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103225/32559